# convert list of dict to list of list python from dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary, list-comprehension

As title.

I have a dataframe column called `column1`:

```
column1
[ {'x': 1, 'y': 0},{'x': 2, 'y': 0},{'x': 4, 'y': 5} ]
[ {'x': 1, 'y': 0},{'x': 0, 'y': 5},{'x': 2, 'y': 0},{'x': 4, 'y': 5} ]
```

Every row is a list of dictionary. I want to transform to list of list like this :

```
column2
[[0,1],[0,2],[5,4]]
[[0,1],[5,0],[0,2],[5,4]]
```

Note that the position of `x` and `y` are reversed to `y` and `x` after transformed.

This is my attempt :

```
[[x['column2']] for x in df['column1']]
```

Receiving error "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str".

I changed to :

```
[[x[0]] for x in df['column1']]
```

I'm not getting the output I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this,

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"column1": [[{'x': 1, 'y': 0}, {'x': 2, 'y': 0}, {'x': 4, 'y': 5}],
                               [{'x': 1, 'y': 0}, {'x': 0, 'y': 5}, {'x': 2, 'y': 0}, {'x': 4, 'y': 5}]]})

df['column2'] = df['column1'].apply(lambda x: [list(v.values())[::-1] for v in x])
```

---

```
0            [[0, 1], [0, 2], [5, 4]]
1    [[0, 1], [5, 0], [0, 2], [5, 4]]

Name: column2, dtype: object
```

Comment: if I do `[list(v.values())[::-1] for v in df['column1']]`, I will get error : `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'values'`

Answer (score 0):

you can use dict values .
this is an example

```
list1 = [ {'x': 1, 'y': 0},{'x': 2, 'y': 0},{'x': 4, 'y': 5} ]
list2 = []
for dic in list1:
    list2.append(list(dic.values()))
print(list2)
```